# Prevent CSS animation after re-showing element

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have an element that will show some animation upon initial page load. After that, the element should be hidden and never show again.

This element is wrapped inside a parent container. Some user interactions may hide the parent container (`display:none` or `hidden` attribute). Every time after the parent container is re-shown, the element is animated again, which I would like to prevent. Why is the element re-animated every time it is re-shown? Any CSS rule to disable this behavior?

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/afu6sdyn/2/). Once you hover over the link and hover out, the element is animated again.

Is it possible to prevent it through pure CSS, not involving any Javascript? How?

Comment: Is it OK to use JavaScript?

Comment: I know how to do it in Javascript, but I want to make it even more simple if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible in pure CSS...

Comment: Why is the element re-animated every time it is re-shown? No CSS rule to disable that?

Comment: You can use `animation-play-state: paused;`, but how will you apply it after first show without JavaScript?

Comment: What's the goal, to re-show the animated element, albeit unanimated, every time, or for it to basically just be gone after the initial animation? I think I can help you out either way, just wanna know which answer to give!

Comment: Be gone after the initial animation. I need pure CSS answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is for the animated element to basically be gone and not overlap anything after the animation is complete, you can take out the forwards state of your animation, and make the inherent height of your .block element 0px. Then set the 0% and 100% keyframes to the height you want (100px), and after the animation is done the block will be gone, for all intents and purposes, having a height of 0 and no clickable area.

```
@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-150%);
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100px;
  }
  15% {
    transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(1);
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
.block{
  width:100px;height:0px;background:black;
  animation: 1.3s 2 alternate drop;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you remove your :hover from the css - switching display from none to anything else resets everything (transitions, animations) in it.

Comment: Please read my original question. I want to prevent the animations after switching from `display:none` to anything else. If not for this purpose, my original animation would work just fine already.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something - above you mentioned that you want the logo to be gone after the initial animation, and this accomplishes that, I thought!

Comment: Yes, even after hovering in and out the link!

Comment: But why does the link have to toggle the display if you want it gone after the animation completes?

Comment: It's a simplified example. In my application, some user interactions will hide and show the parent container.